# PHP Mess Detector avoid using static access

Tags: laravel, controller, phpmd, illuminate

i use PHP Mess Detector on my Laravel controller invokable class and i got message like this

```
Avoid using static access to class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache' in method '__invoke'
```

Can anyone explain it why i must avoid using static access on invoke method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Static access causes unexchangeable dependencies to other classes and
>   leads to hard to test code. Avoid using static access at all costs and
>   instead inject dependencies through the constructor. The only case
>   when static access is acceptable is when used for factory methods.

Reference: https://phpmd.org/rules/cleancode.html#staticaccess

Comment: Ok.. thank's now i know the reason why must avoid it